# How to find out NOT NULL attributes in tables

Tags: sql-server, query

I need a query that returns a list of attributes in a table that cannot be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to find this information:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<table name here>' 
    AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'
```